# How to implement swiping ion-items in Ionic without clicking?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement an ion-list with ion-items that are swipable but don't have to be clicked on the side to trigger an event.

It should work like like the default contacts app on Samsung phones, where you can either swipe left to call or right to send a SMS.

The list in the parent page looks like this:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let person of persons | filter:searchTerm">
   <app-person-entry [person]="person" (click)="openModal(person)"></app-person-entry>
</ion-list>
```

The person-entry component looks like this:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-avatar slot="start">
    <img src={{person.icon}}>
  </ion-avatar>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <ion-label>{{person.lastname}}</ion-label>
      <ion-label>{{person.firstname}}</ion-label>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <ion-label>{{person.postalCode}}</ion-label>
      <ion-label>{{person.city}}</ion-label>
      <ion-label>{{person.address}}</ion-label>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ion-item-sliding`.
e.g:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item-group #myItemsId>
      <ion-item-sliding (ionSwipe)="swipeEvent($event, myItemsId)">
        <ion-item-options side="start">
          <ion-item-option>CALL</ion-item-option>
        </ion-item-options>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Item Options</ion-label>
        </ion-item>


        <ion-item-options side="end">
          <ion-item-option>SMS</ion-item-option>
        </ion-item-options>

      </ion-item-sliding>
    </ion-item-group>
  </ion-list>
```

.ts:

```
swipeEvent($event, item) {
    console.log($event)
    if ($event.detail.side == 'start') {
      console.log('call now');
      this.closeAllItems(item)
    } else {
      console.log('SMS now');
      this.closeAllItems(item)
    }
  }

  closeAllItems(item) {
    let a = Array.prototype.slice.call(item.el.children)
    a.map((val) => {
      val.close();
    })
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of these call/sms boxes and simply reset the ion-item if you have swiped? (no clicking)

Comment: oh, are you talking about swipe gestures?

Comment: Like in this video at 1:00:
https://youtu.be/aEvFO1ma-8A

Comment: As seen in the VIDEO above code will work.

Comment: But the boxes on the side don't dissappear? After you have swiped

Comment: you can make is disappear. will update my answer tomorrow.

Comment: I have updated my answer. now items will get closed automatically.

Comment: Please Accept answer so others can get help. Upvote as well.